# What is the average cost to migrate from India to either Australia, Canada or New Zealand?

Tags: immigration, canada, australia, new-zealand

I'm analyzing my options as the best country to move to with my family. Immigration is always a big deal and finances are an important aspect of this process.

I'd like to inquire what is the cost to migrate from India to either Australia, Canada or New Zealand? What fees might be needed for obtaining a PR for these countries?

**EDIT**:
Based on ***outflak's*** comment:

Family Size - Single (1)/Unmarried

Exchange Rate - INR

I'm looking for a ball park figure needed *before the actual move* i.e immigration process fee, consultancy fee, visa fee etc

I currently have a budget of ~3.5lakh INR (350000 INR approximately equal to CAD$6650) for pre-flight expenses. Will that suffice?

Comment: Depends on a lot of factors including: on what basis you plan to immigrate, family size, exchange rates, costs of living, where in the respective country you'll work, and even demand for your profession (employees might be willing to help with costs). Narrow things down from a different perspective. How much are you willing to spend?

Comment: Canada's express entry: http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/funds.asp

Comment: On the link mkennedy have, you need over 12,000 Canadian dollars. And as ouflak said, other factors complicate this: Australia may even help pay for you to migrate if you have a skill they need and you are willing to live away from a big city.

Comment: On what basis are you planning to immigrate. As a skilled professional? You said you wanted to move with your family, but then state that you are single. Are you asking in preparation of establishing a family and then immigrating (which has significantly different costs)? Or do you want to immigrate as an unskilled worker and then establish a familly there? Or perhaps as a skilled worker and then establish a family. Or maybe get married first...? So many possibilities. You really need to narrow down your exact plan. mkennedy has provided a link for a single skilled professional.

Comment: *  as a skilled worker (IT) and then establish a family

Comment: I've heard second hand that fees for skilled migration to Australia were around $6k, but I think that was for a family of 4.

Comment: Spoke to an  immigration consultant for Australia & Canada PRs. She said to expect around 4.5 lakh pre-flight expenditure. Now I just need to research on NZ and save more moolah! Tnx everyone!